# Arduino read from port 1, send to port 0

Tags: serialization, arduino

I got this snippet of code from the Blueduino board manufacturer's page. It works fantastically for two-way communication, it seemed simple but after much searching I can't understand what it is doing.

This is the code:

```
// read from port 1, send to port 0:
if (Serial1.available()) {
  int inByte = Serial1.read();
  Serial.write(inByte);
}

// read from port 0, send to port 1:
if (Serial.available()) {
  int inByte = Serial.read();
  Serial1.write(inByte);
}
```

It's obvious it's writing the in to the out and vice-versa (Rx to Tx I believe) but I am not sure why.

This code is working and when I write in the serial monitor it is received on the phone, but I'm not sure how this code is taking the message I send in the serial monitor and inserting it in the stream.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is forwarding messages from one serial device to another.
Most likely between your Arduinos serial interface (to your pc) to the blueduino board.
You cannot connect your PC to the Phone directly and you cannot wire the blueduino-board directly to the serial lines of your PC.

Hence you need something in between. (your arduino) that forwards every single byte.

The code you have basically does the same for both ports. If a byte is in the serial receive buffer, read it and send it to the other port.

Comment: Thanks for that, that is what I thought. The blueduino is connected to an app in my phone directly over ble bluetooth. What I am really trying to wrap my brain around is how the message is getting into the stream with this code. If I go to the serial monitor and type something and press send it comes up on my phone and similarly if I go to my phone app and type somthing in it will appear on the serial monitor. What I can't understand is how this code is achieving this?

Comment: which stream do you mean? and what about the code is it you do not understand?

Comment: The buffer (data stream)

Comment: The code seems to me like it would just output whatever comes in. So if I say hello on my phone it outputs to the arduino. And if I say goodbye on the arduino that would be sent to the phone. But what I can't understand if the usual line to write to the serial port is serial,write and this command has already been called by this code how is the monitor able to insert the word I have just written. Sorry its hard to explain.

Comment: What I am trying to do is get an analog value from the arduino and then fet the phone to send back commands to the arduino based on the analog value.but every mod to the code I end up with nothing coming back on either side. So i am trying to understand how the message from th serial monitor is being used by this code....

Comment: If you send a message from your pc or from your phone it will end up in one of your Arduinos receive buffers. One byte after another (of course everything happens very quickly). The code will check if something is in the receive buffers (Serial.available() and if so, read the content and send it to the other serial port (where it is written into the write buffer and from there into the receive buffer of your phone or pc). the code is ment to be used in a loop so you can constantly check if there at least 1 new byte in the receive buffer you can forward...  still not sure what you're asking